# How to check maximum frequency generation capability PWM of microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, frequency, texas-instruments

I am new to Texas Instruments Controller. By checking the datasheet how can we come to know about the maximum output frequncy generation of PWM of the controller. Is it related to the clock frequency of Microcontroller?
Thank You

Comment: Which TI controller? In general, find the fastest clock that can drive the timer that drives the PWM with the smallest divider. Then divide by the resolution that you require.

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, the fastest PWM speed available depends on which clock the PWM hardware peripheral is inheriting, and which divisor options the PWM peripheral got. Some PWM peripherals might be able to work at system clock, others at raw external oscillator clock, others system clock divided by something.

Many MCUs also have multiple available PWM resolutions (8, 16, 32 bits), which may affect speed.

And finally the port I/O will have an activation delay, we are talking nanoseconds there.